# Expandable list view only one child is showing

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I have a expandable list view also am passing parent items and child items via arraylist..I can see only the first parent child..by clicking other items nothing happens

The activity and expandable list view adapter codes are given below

```js
 expandableList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.exlist);
  
  expandableList.setDividerHeight(2);
  expandableList.setGroupIndicator(null);
  expandableList.setClickable(true);

  setGroupParents();
  setChildData();

  MyExpandableAdapter exadapter = new MyExpandableAdapter(data);
  
  exadapter.setInflater((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE), this);
  expandableList.setAdapter(exadapter);
//  expandableList.setOnChildClickListener(this);
  expandableList.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
     int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
   }
  });
```

```js
package com.javacodegeeks.android.loginapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MyExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

 private Activity activity;
 private ArrayList<Object> childtems;
 private String parent;
 private LayoutInflater inflater;
 private ArrayList<String> parentItems;
 ArrayList<ObjectModelClass> data;
 ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> nodes = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

 ArrayList<String> childs=new ArrayList<String>();
 public MyExpandableAdapter(ArrayList<String> parents, ArrayList<Object> childern) {
  this.parentItems = parents;
  this.childtems = childern;
 }

 public MyExpandableAdapter(ArrayList<ObjectModelClass> data) {
  
  this.data=data;
  
  
 }

 public void setInflater(LayoutInflater inflater, Activity activity) {
  this.inflater = inflater;
  this.activity = activity;
 }

 
 
 @Override
 public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  
  String child = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
  ChildViewHolder childHolder;
  
  if (convertView == null) {
   childHolder = new ChildViewHolder();
   convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group, null);
   childHolder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
   childHolder.textPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
   convertView.setTag(childHolder);
  }
  else
  {
   childHolder = (ChildViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
  }
  
  
  childHolder.textView.setText(child);
  
  
  
  return convertView;
 }
 
 private static class ChildViewHolder
 {
  TextView textView;
  TextView textPrice;
 }
 @Override
 public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  
  if (convertView == null) {
   convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_ex, null);
  }
  
  ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setText(data.get(groupPosition).getTitle());
  ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);
  
  return convertView;
 }

 @Override
 public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
  return data.get(groupPosition).getChildren().get(childPosition);
 }

 @Override
 public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
  return 0;
 }

 
 @Override
 public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
  System.out.println(groupPosition);
  return data.get(groupPosition).getChildren().size();
 }

 @Override
 public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
  return data.get(groupPosition);
 }

 @Override
 public int getGroupCount() {
  return data.size();
 }



 
 
 

 @Override
 public boolean hasStableIds() {
  return false;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
  return false;
 }

 @Override
 public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return 0;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return data.get(groupPosition).getChildren().get(childPosition);
}
```

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from ObjectModelClass to long --got this error when i changed the code

Comment: your code is working fine for me, just check your input has the childs list or not.

Answer (score 0):

Change the children count to data.get(groupPosition).getChildren().size();